# MVC3 Getting a 'property field is required' error despite having no [Required] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, validation

I have this code:

```
@this.Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.FishId, 
    new SelectList(this.Model.Fishies, "FishId", "FishName", this.Model.FishId), "Please Select a Fish")

@this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(vm => vm.FishId)
```

The model for this is simply

```
public int FishId
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

So there is no validation here. When I press submit, I get a message saying `The FishId Field is Required.`. This is a client-side validation error. Any idea what's causing this?

If I change the validation message for, to this:

```
@this.Html.ValidationMessageFor(vm => vm.FishId, "Gotta select a fish, man")
```

Then the error message changes (which is what I want) to the right of the dropdown, however the validation summary still displays the original message.

All of my other stuff I put validation and messages either as RequiredField(...) attributes, or in a custom validation method.

What's going on, how can I change the validation summary message?

Comment: what does your controller method look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you want to disable the validation or change the error message. If the latter, then you should try adding the below to your model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Gotta select a fish, man")]
public int FishId {get;set;}
```

Comment: Turns out this worked better, I had tried this, but like the buffoon I am, I had applied it to the wrong view model! Cheers:)

Comment: I basically have this exact set up (here in 2017) and yet I keep getting what appears to be the default 'Required' message instead of the `ErrorMessage` that I set. :(

Answer (score 11):

Try put the int to nullable

```
public int? FishId { get; set; }
```

It should pass validation because you allow null values

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying MVC is going 'this isnt nullable so i will put default validation in'? Is it possible to keep it non-nullable but customise the error message in the validation summary? Otherwise I'll have to do some server-side validation.

Comment: You can create you own valdiation attribute, so you can handle the way you like how DoprDownList validation should work. Other way you have to work server side. there is also RemoteValidation, but i'm not sure if can work the way you like, because I never used it for something like that

Answer (score 1):

Create The instance and pass it to open result....

Example: return View("Add", new Customer());

This will initialize all value types with default values.